# Find the greatest date value between columns with NULL values in oracle sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this in Oracle SQL developer but with multiples id. Every id has a row for each month

| date | date became A | date became B | date became column C | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-OCT-17 | 01-MAR-18 | 01-OCT-17 | NULL | 1 |
| 01-NOV-17 | 01-MAR-18 | 01-OCT-17 | NULL | 1 |
| 01-DEC-17 | 01-MAR-18 | 01-OCT-17 | NULL | 1 |
| 01-JAN-18 | 01-MAR-18 | 01-OCT-17 | NULL | 1 |
| 01-FEB-18 | 01-MAR-18 | 01-OCT-17 | NULL | 1 |
| 01-MAR-18 | 01-MAR-18 | 01-OCT-17 | NULL | 1 |

How to i select, per id, only the line where the `date` column is equal to the max value across columns `date date became A`, `date date became B`, `date date became C`? I was trying to use the `GREATEST()` but it seens to considere the column with the `NULL` the greatest one

Comment: What is desired result, in this case? BTW, if you want to select something that is "equal to MIN value", then GREATEST function is not the best choice.

Comment: @Littlefoot i did not show the entire table and it was max not min (i have already edited the post). The desired result was the first row since it is the row with the date that is equal to the minimal date across the 3 columns (1-oct-17)

Comment: How is 01-OCT-17 the MAX date for the first column? Shouldn't it be 01-MAR-18?

Comment: sorry @Littlefoot you are right, should be 01-mar-18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to craft the ordering very carefully to correctly deal with nulls.

You can do:

```
select *
from (
  select t.*,
    row_number() over(
      partition by id
      order by case when a > b then case when c > a then c else a end
                    when a < b then case when c > b then c else b end
                    else c end DESC
    ) as rn
  from t
) x
where rn = 1
```

Comment: i solved my problem, it was not exactly like you row but you sugestion helped a lot, THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

Read comments within code.

Some sample data:

```
SQL> with
  2  test (datum, datum_a, datum_b, datum_c, id) as
  3    (select date '2017-10-01', date '2018-03-01', date '2017-10-01', null, 1 from dual union all
  4     select date '2017-11-01', date '2018-03-01', date '2017-10-01', null, 1 from dual union all
  5     select date '2018-03-01', date '2018-03-01', date '2017-10-01', null, 1 from dual
  6    ),
```

This (01-jan-1900) is used as the lowest date you can have. It is then used in the `NVL` function, to avoid `NULL` *problem* with the `GREATEST` function. I guess that's better than just hardcoding it

```
  7  absolute_min_date (datum) as
  8    (select date '1900-01-01' from dual),
```

Find max `datum` (of all 4 date columns) per each id

```
  9  max_datum_per_id as
 10    (select t.id, max(greatest(nvl(t.datum  , a.datum),
 11                               nvl(t.datum_a, a.datum),
 12                               nvl(t.datum_b, a.datum),
 13                               nvl(t.datum_c, a.datum)
 14                             )) max_overall_datum
 15     from test t cross join absolute_min_date a
 16     group by t.id
 17    )
```

Finally, take row (from the "original" table) whose `ID` and `datum` match values from the previous CTE

```
 18  select t.*
 19  from test t join max_datum_per_id m on m.id = t.id and m.max_overall_datum = t.datum;

DATUM     DATUM_A   DATUM_B   DATUM_C            ID
--------- --------- --------- ---------- ----------
01-mar-18 01-mar-18 01-oct-17                     1

SQL>
```

---

At the end, I'm not sure whether you want `MAX` (which goes along with the `GREATEST` function) or `MIN` (so you'd use `LEAST`) because your title/message text/comments differ from each other.

Comment: its not because the dates in columns A, B and C could be before the max date in the date column. I need to select the row where the column data is equal to the max date of the dates in columns A, B, C

Comment: Aha. I completely misunderstood what you wanted. See edited answer.